# How can I transform a Map of Lists based on one of the lists in Java?

Tags: java

I am working with stats from a system monitoring tool (sar to be specific) and I am trying to re-structure them. I receive all the data in the JSON format. In Java, the received JSON is represented as a `Map<String, Object>` and stored in the variable `dataMap`.

Below is an example of 1 minutes worth of processor stats:

```
{
  "processor_time":["08:59:01 AM","08:59:01 AM","08:59:01 AM","08:59:01 AM","08:59:01 AM","08:59:01 AM","08:59:01 AM","08:59:01 AM","08:59:01 AM","08:59:01 AM","08:59:01 AM","08:59:01 AM","08:59:01 AM","08:59:01 AM","08:59:01 AM","08:59:01 AM","08:59:01 AM","08:59:01 AM","08:59:01 AM","08:59:01 AM","08:59:01 AM","08:59:01 AM","08:59:01 AM","08:59:01 AM","08:59:01 AM"],
  "processor_CPU":["all",0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23],
  "processor_%user":[1.6,8.78,2.32,1.67,1.78,1.23,3.83,3.57,0.93,0.62,0.32,0.48,0.37,3.94,1.25,1.22,1.04,0.78,0.65,1.2,0.57,0.4,0.87,0.25,0.38],
  "processor_%nice":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  "processor_%system":[0.4,2.57,0.65,0.45,0.62,0.32,0.93,0.22,0.2,0.17,0.15,0.15,0.13,0.75,0.32,0.18,0.37,0.25,0.22,0.13,0.22,0.1,0.22,0.08,0.22],
  "processor_%iowait":[0.01,0,0.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.03,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  "processor_%steal":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  "processor_%idle":[97.99,88.65,96.93,97.88,97.6,98.45,95.23,96.22,98.87,99.22,99.53,99.37,99.5,95.31,98.4,98.6,98.6,98.97,99.13,98.67,99.22,99.5,98.92,99.67,99.4]
}
```

I have already pulled this out of `dataMap` and collated it on a per-minute basis. The following code shows this:

```
// declared per minute map
Map<Integer, Object> perMinuteMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
// Narrowed in on the sar stat details.
// detailsList would be pull out of dataMap, the inbound JSON map
List<Map<String, Object>> detailsList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Map<String, Object> entry : detailsList)
{
   List<String> headers = (List<String>) entry.get("headers");
   String type = (String) entry.get("type");
   List<List<Object>> data = (List<List<Object>>) entry.get("data");
   // Loop through the list of data a given type
   for (List<Object> dataDetails : data)
   {
      // Variables
      String timeString = (String) dataDetails.get(0);
      Integer extractedMinute = new Integer(-1);

      // Minute extraction
      if (!timeString.contains("Average"))
      {
         DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss a");
         LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(timeString, formatter);
         DateTimeFormatter formatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE;
         extractedMinute = Integer.valueOf(time.getMinute());
      }
      String field = "";
      int dataDetailsSize = dataDetails.size();
      // loop through the individual data points.
      for (int i = 0; i < dataDetailsSize; i++)
      {
         List<Object> dataList;
         Object dataPoint = dataDetails.get(i);
         if (i < headers.size())
         {
            field = type + "_" + headers.get(i);
         }
         else
         {
            field = type + "_unknown";
         }

         if (extractedMinute != Integer.valueOf(-1))
         {
            LinkedHashMap<String, Object> explodedMinute = (LinkedHashMap<String, Object>) perMinuteMap
                  .get(extractedMinute);

            if (null != explodedMinute)
            {
               dataList = (List<Object>) explodedMinute.get(field);
               if (null != dataList)
               {
                  dataList.add(dataPoint);
                  explodedMinute.put(field, dataList);
               }
               else
               {
                  dataList = new ArrayList<>();
                  dataList.add(dataPoint);
                  explodedMinute.put(field, dataList);
               }
               perMinuteMap.put(extractedMinute, explodedMinute);
            }
            else
            {
               explodedMinute = new LinkedHashMap<>();
               dataList = new ArrayList<>();
               dataList.add(dataPoint);
               explodedMinute.put(field, dataList);
               perMinuteMap.put(extractedMinute, explodedMinute);
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I used to following, plus some manual formatting, to structure the JSON I had posted up above.

```
  // Loop through each key, value of a Map
  perMinuteMap.forEach((key, value) ->
  {
     String json_minute_string;
     try
     {
        json_minute_string = mapper.writeValueAsString(value);
        System.out.println(json_minute_string);
     }
     catch (JsonProcessingException e)
     {
        log.error("Unexpected Exception", e);
     }
  });
```

I am looking to restructure the data and collate the stats keying on the value of `processor_CPU`. For example, it should like something like the following:

```
{
  "processor_%user": {
    "CPU_all": [1.6],
    "CPU_1": [8.78]
  },
  "processor_%nice": {
    "CPU_all": [0],
    "CPU_1": [0]
  }
}
```

The restructured data will not have the `processor_time` and `processor_CPU` fields.

Ultimately, I am aiming to loop through the data and append each minute's data point to these inner list, such that they will eventually have 60 elements in each of them.

Please advise on how I can do this sort of transformation.

Comment: Have you written any code? Where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: Where did you get `[1]` and `[6]` from? Should it be `[1.6]` and `[8.78]`?

Comment: I have written code that takes in 1 hours worth of data and and re-structures it into per-minute `Map` containing a Map with the keys being the field names and the values being a list of values (in order) for that field in that minute. I am stuck on trying to apply the transformation I described to a minutes worth of data a given segment. In this case, the segment is the processor data.

Comment: Thanks Sedrick. Corrected question. That is what I am aiming for.

Comment: @shmosel : I have edited the question to include some of the code I have already written. This was used to process the inbound JSON into a per-minute map and dump the JSON I used in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a terrible answer due to no explanation. You can read the code to see if you can get an understanding. If I get enough down votes, I will delete it in a couple of days.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 *
 * @author Sedrick
 */
public class JavaApplication3 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        String str1 = "\"processor_time\":\"08:59:01 AM\",\"08:59:01 AM\",\"08:59:01 AM\",\"08:59:01 AM\",\"08:59:01 AM\",\"08:59:01 AM\",\"08:59:01 AM\"," 
                     +  "\"08:59:01 AM\",\"08:59:01 AM\",\"08:59:01 AM\",\"08:59:01 AM\",\"08:59:01 AM\",\"08:59:01 AM\",\"08:59:01 AM\",\"08:59:01 AM\",\"08:59:01 AM\",\"08:59:01 AM\",\"08:59:01 AM\","
                     + "\"08:59:01 AM\",\"08:59:01 AM\",\"08:59:01 AM\",\"08:59:01 AM\",\"08:59:01 AM\",\"08:59:01 AM\",\"08:59:01 AM\",";

        String str2 = "\"processor_CPU\":\"all\",0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23";
        String str3 = "\"processor_%user\":1.6,8.78,2.32,1.67,1.78,1.23,3.83,3.57,0.93,0.62,0.32,0.48,0.37,3.94,1.25,1.22,1.04,0.78,0.65,1.2,0.57,0.4,0.87,0.25,0.38";
        String str4 = "\"processor_%nice\":0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0";
        String str5 = "\"processor_%system\":0.4,2.57,0.65,0.45,0.62,0.32,0.93,0.22,0.2,0.17,0.15,0.15,0.13,0.75,0.32,0.18,0.37,0.25,0.22,0.13,0.22,0.1,0.22,0.08,0.22";
        String str6 = "\"processor_%iowait\":0.01,0,0.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.03,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0";
        String str7 = "\"processor_%steal\":0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0";
        String str8 = "\"processor_%idle\":97.99,88.65,96.93,97.88,97.6,98.45,95.23,96.22,98.87,99.22,99.53,99.37,99.5,95.31,98.4,98.6,98.6,98.97,99.13,98.67,99.22,99.5,98.92,99.67,99.4";

        List<String> strings = new ArrayList();
        strings.add(str1);
        strings.add(str2);
        strings.add(str3);
        strings.add(str4);
        strings.add(str5);
        strings.add(str6);
        strings.add(str7);
        strings.add(str8);

        Map<String, List<String>> map1 = new LinkedHashMap();
        Map<String, List<String>> map2 = new LinkedHashMap();


        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            String key = stringToList(strings.get(i)).get(0);
            List<String> values = stringToList(strings.get(i)).subList(1, stringToList(strings.get(i)).size() - 1);
            map1.put(key, values);
        }

        List<String> keyHolder = new ArrayList();        
        for(int i = 2; i < strings.size(); i++)
        {
            String key = stringToList(strings.get(i)).get(0);
            List<String> values = stringToList(strings.get(i)).subList(1, stringToList(strings.get(i)).size() - 1);
            map2.put(key, values);
            keyHolder.add(key);
        }        

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        stringBuilder.append("{\n");
        for(int i = 0; i < keyHolder.size(); i++)//Take first two
        {
            stringBuilder.append("\t").append(keyHolder.get(i)).append(": {\n");
            for(int z = 0; z < map1.get("\"processor_CPU\"").size(); z++)
            {
                stringBuilder.append("\t\t\"CPU_").append(map1.get("\"processor_CPU\"").get(z).replace("\"", "")).append("\": [").append(map2.get(keyHolder.get(i)).get(z)).append("],\n");
            }

            String tempString = stringBuilder.substring(0, stringBuilder.length() - 2);
            stringBuilder.setLength(0);
            stringBuilder.append(tempString).append("\n\t},\n");
        }

        String tempString = stringBuilder.substring(0, stringBuilder.length() - 2);
        stringBuilder.setLength(0);
        stringBuilder.append(tempString).append("\n}");

        System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
    }


    static public List<String> stringToList(String str)
    {
        List<String> tempList = new ArrayList();

        String key = str.split(":", 2)[0].trim();
        String[] tailItems = str.split(":", 2)[1].trim().split(",");

        tempList.add(key);
        for(int i = 0; i < tailItems.length; i++)
        {
            tempList.add(tailItems[i].trim());
        }

        return tempList;
    }
}
```

> Outputun:

```
{
    "processor_%user": {
        "CPU_all": [1.6],
        "CPU_0": [8.78],
        "CPU_1": [2.32],
        "CPU_2": [1.67],
        "CPU_3": [1.78],
        "CPU_4": [1.23],
        "CPU_5": [3.83],
        "CPU_6": [3.57],
        "CPU_7": [0.93],
        "CPU_8": [0.62],
        "CPU_9": [0.32],
        "CPU_10": [0.48],
        "CPU_11": [0.37],
        "CPU_12": [3.94],
        "CPU_13": [1.25],
        "CPU_14": [1.22],
        "CPU_15": [1.04],
        "CPU_16": [0.78],
        "CPU_17": [0.65],
        "CPU_18": [1.2],
        "CPU_19": [0.57],
        "CPU_20": [0.4],
        "CPU_21": [0.87],
        "CPU_22": [0.25]
    },
    "processor_%nice": {
        "CPU_all": [0],
        "CPU_0": [0],
        "CPU_1": [0],
        "CPU_2": [0],
        "CPU_3": [0],
        "CPU_4": [0],
        "CPU_5": [0],
        "CPU_6": [0],
        "CPU_7": [0],
        "CPU_8": [0],
        "CPU_9": [0],
        "CPU_10": [0],
        "CPU_11": [0],
        "CPU_12": [0],
        "CPU_13": [0],
        "CPU_14": [0],
        "CPU_15": [0],
        "CPU_16": [0],
        "CPU_17": [0],
        "CPU_18": [0],
        "CPU_19": [0],
        "CPU_20": [0],
        "CPU_21": [0],
        "CPU_22": [0]
    },
    "processor_%system": {
        "CPU_all": [0.4],
        "CPU_0": [2.57],
        "CPU_1": [0.65],
        "CPU_2": [0.45],
        "CPU_3": [0.62],
        "CPU_4": [0.32],
        "CPU_5": [0.93],
        "CPU_6": [0.22],
        "CPU_7": [0.2],
        "CPU_8": [0.17],
        "CPU_9": [0.15],
        "CPU_10": [0.15],
        "CPU_11": [0.13],
        "CPU_12": [0.75],
        "CPU_13": [0.32],
        "CPU_14": [0.18],
        "CPU_15": [0.37],
        "CPU_16": [0.25],
        "CPU_17": [0.22],
        "CPU_18": [0.13],
        "CPU_19": [0.22],
        "CPU_20": [0.1],
        "CPU_21": [0.22],
        "CPU_22": [0.08]
    },
    "processor_%iowait": {
        "CPU_all": [0.01],
        "CPU_0": [0],
        "CPU_1": [0.1],
        "CPU_2": [0],
        "CPU_3": [0],
        "CPU_4": [0],
        "CPU_5": [0],
        "CPU_6": [0],
        "CPU_7": [0],
        "CPU_8": [0],
        "CPU_9": [0],
        "CPU_10": [0],
        "CPU_11": [0],
        "CPU_12": [0],
        "CPU_13": [0.03],
        "CPU_14": [0],
        "CPU_15": [0],
        "CPU_16": [0],
        "CPU_17": [0],
        "CPU_18": [0],
        "CPU_19": [0],
        "CPU_20": [0],
        "CPU_21": [0],
        "CPU_22": [0]
    },
    "processor_%steal": {
        "CPU_all": [0],
        "CPU_0": [0],
        "CPU_1": [0],
        "CPU_2": [0],
        "CPU_3": [0],
        "CPU_4": [0],
        "CPU_5": [0],
        "CPU_6": [0],
        "CPU_7": [0],
        "CPU_8": [0],
        "CPU_9": [0],
        "CPU_10": [0],
        "CPU_11": [0],
        "CPU_12": [0],
        "CPU_13": [0],
        "CPU_14": [0],
        "CPU_15": [0],
        "CPU_16": [0],
        "CPU_17": [0],
        "CPU_18": [0],
        "CPU_19": [0],
        "CPU_20": [0],
        "CPU_21": [0],
        "CPU_22": [0]
    },
    "processor_%idle": {
        "CPU_all": [97.99],
        "CPU_0": [88.65],
        "CPU_1": [96.93],
        "CPU_2": [97.88],
        "CPU_3": [97.6],
        "CPU_4": [98.45],
        "CPU_5": [95.23],
        "CPU_6": [96.22],
        "CPU_7": [98.87],
        "CPU_8": [99.22],
        "CPU_9": [99.53],
        "CPU_10": [99.37],
        "CPU_11": [99.5],
        "CPU_12": [95.31],
        "CPU_13": [98.4],
        "CPU_14": [98.6],
        "CPU_15": [98.6],
        "CPU_16": [98.97],
        "CPU_17": [99.13],
        "CPU_18": [98.67],
        "CPU_19": [99.22],
        "CPU_20": [99.5],
        "CPU_21": [98.92],
        "CPU_22": [99.67]
    }
}
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```